# Changing URL path of API in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, url, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django web app and it's running really fine and well, but I'm facing a small issue where after I deployed the app on a VPS, the Django Rest Framework default API URL is pointing at the home IP address like in the image below.

[image]

The issue here is that when I'm running my app on the server, the above highlighted URL is directing me toward my home IP address on my local machine.
How can I change this URL with the IP address of the VPS or domain? Is that possible?

---

**Edit - 1:**

Below is the code of my `urls.py` file if it can help

```
from django.views.static import serve

router = routers.DefaultRouter()    
router.register(r'artfairs', views.ArtFairViewSet)
router.register(r'inquiries', views.InquiryViewSet)
router.register(r'mediums', views.MediumViewSet)
router.register(r'origins', views.OriginViewSet)
router.register(r'styles', views.StyleViewSet)
router.register(r'types', views.TypeViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'artists', views.ArtistViewSet)
router.register(r'artworks', views.ArtworkViewSet)
router.register(r'shipping-addresses', views.ShippingAddressViewSet)
router.register(r'user-addresses', views.UserAddressViewSet)

router.register(
    r'artworks-by-artist',
    views.ArtworksByArtistViewSet,
    basename='artworks-by-artist',
)

router.register(
    r'cart',
    views.CartViewSet,
    basename='cart',
)

router.register(
    r'latest-artworks',
    views.LatestArtworksViewSet,
    basename='latest-artworks',
)

router.register(
    r'wishlist',
    views.WishListViewSet,
    basename='wishlist',
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),

    # media and static files paths
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),

    # paths related to JWT Authentication
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(),
         name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/',
         TokenRefreshView.as_view(),
         name='token_refresh'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: share your urls.py files. This should automaticly added hosted vps base_url in place of localhost.

Comment: @mehedi will edit the post

Comment: I suspect the culprit might be somewhere in the server settings. DRF should automatically pick up the proper URL. The code you posted looks ok. Is that an Apache server? NGINX?

Comment: @cezar It's Nginx

Comment: can you share serializers.py, i think you need to make custom URL serializer to overwrite this

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I was finally able to find my answer in these 2 links. The first one was from DRF documentation while the other one is a question previously asked on stackoverflow.

> [Routers Page in Django Rest Framework Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)
>
> [How to change the Django Rest Framework's default url to a custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231393/how-to-change-the-django-rest-frameworks-default-url-to-a-custom)

**I edited my `location` settings to look like this:**

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/root/<my_app_directory>/<my_app.sock>;
}
```